# Does the sine rule ever give you the obtuse angle?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

Why does the sine rule produce the acute angle, and will it ever produce the correct obtuse one?

For example if you have a triangle ABC, where angle CAB is 27 degrees, CB is 7cm, and AB is 12cm. When finding the angle ACB, sine rule produces 51.

From the diagram below, it nicely shows that the sine rule is assuming you are talking about triangle ADB (I know the sine rule has no autonomy but didn't know how else to phrase it). Why doesn't it assume that it's triangle ACB? And would there ever be a time when it does?

[image]

Comment: With the sine rule, you get $\sin(\angle BCA)=\frac{12}7\sin(27^\circ)\approx0.778$, which has two solutions in $[0,\pi]$: They are approximately $51.1^\circ$ and $128.9^\circ$.

Answer (score 5):

I'll try to clear up any sources of confusion here.

By the sine rule, we know that
$$\frac{\sin(\angle ACB)}{12}=\frac{\sin(\angle CAB)}{7}\implies \sin(\angle ACB)=\frac{12}{7}\sin27^\circ.$$
Now, when we plug this into our calculator only gives us one value, and the angle it gives us will be in the range $-90^\circ\leqslant \angle ACB\leqslant 90^\circ$. The reason for this is that the inverse $\sin$ function ($\arcsin$ or $\sin^{-1}$) only takes values between $-90^\circ$ and $90^\circ$. The reason for *this* is to ensure that the inverse $\sin$ function is [one-to-one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection).

So our calculator will tell us that
$$\angle ACB=\arcsin \left(\frac{12}{7}\sin27^\circ\right)=51.10...^\circ.$$
However, it is important to remember the identity
$$\sin\theta\equiv \sin(180^\circ-\theta).$$
This means that if an angle $\theta$ is a solution to our equation, then so is $180^\circ-\theta$. In our case, we have $\theta=51.10...^\circ$, and so the other solution is $\theta=180-51.10...=128.90...^\circ$.

Therefore, the sine rule actually does give us two solutions- it's only our calculators that restrict it to one (acute) solution :)

---

I hope that helps. If you have any questions please don't hesitate to ask :)

Comment: To cite a maybe more familiar situation to the OP: If you want to solve $x^2=4$, using the square root function on a calculator will give you $2$ as the answer, ignoring that $-2$ is a solution as well. In cases where the original function is not one-to-one, there are conventions which result the inverse function gives. For square vs. square root the convention is that the nonnegative solution is given. For sine vs. arcsine, it is that a solution between -90° and +90° is given. In both cases, you have to check if the "omitted" solutions might work for your problem.

Comment: @Ingix Excellent example, thanks!